# QGIS: Raster Processing slow but CPU at 0%

Tags: qgis

I have looked up some topics about QGIS being slow but what I don't understand is why using, for example, Clip Raster by Extent, and selecting a small rectangle, takes a long time (I cancelled after 20 minutes) even though my CPU is at 0%

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The remote image seems to be a well organized Cloud Optimised GeoTIFF that can be read in an effective way without downloading the whole image. I cannot say what trouble QGIS has but I re-wrote the GDAL command and tried it from the command line. It took 20 seconds to save the requested part of the image.

```
The current time is: 15.17.59,66

gdal_translate -projwin 419025 4692392 434143 4679207 -of GTiff /vsicurl/https://datacloud.icgc.cat/datacloud/met5_ETRS89/mosaic/met5_catalunya_2020.tif output.tif
Input file size is 56344, 55812
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

The current time is: 15.18.19,84
```

You can try to check if QGIS has some problem with net traffic with the Network logger that is in the development tools. You can open them with function key 12 or from View - Panels - Debugging/Development tools.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I manually edit the command?

Comment: @Moseleyi install GDAL on your computer, then you can open `cmd` (if you're on Windows) and enter GDAL commands like the one above. You can check GDAL installed correctly by running the command `gdalinfo --version`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do that when I get some time. Thank you for running it on your side and confirming it is supposed to be fast : )